# Why does the Windows command prompt say "More? " when I run a program with an argument of d^?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, command-prompt

I was making a C++ calculator program that removes unrecognized text from the argument array, and I just so happened to enter d^ when I was running the program. The Windows command prompt then showed "More? ", and I couldn't figure out why, since I didn't script this. I realized it was coming up since I wrote d^, but why does it do this? What does "More? " do?

Note: Compiled in Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop, if you need to know.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++; this happens even if you just open up a command prompt and type in `d^`, without any other program running. In fact, this is true regardless of whether you type in `d` first at all (or any other character, for that matter; try, e.g., `bc^` - it'll give you the same output).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`More?` "does" nothing. It asks you to continue your command.

`^` is an "escape character" that tells the Interpreter to treat the following character different. The following character is a Line End ("Enter") - `^` tells the Interpreter not to handle it as end of line ("Enter"), so it asks you to continue.

Comment: Is the prompt configurable? There's `%PROMPT%` value (that is set to `$P$G`) in `cmd.exe`, but I couldn't find `$PS2` analogue, as with Bash.

Comment: @Elvin; `prompt /?` tells you all the different variables. It doesn't apply to the `More?` prompt though.